# Updating/Insert 2 different models on same screen?  

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity

I am working on an edit view that allows a user to edit a particular entity.  One of the drop down menus needs to allow the user to create a new instance of a different related entity if they don't see one that exists already.  I'm trying to figure out the best practice for this.

The model they are editing:

```
 public class SurveyProgramModel
    {

        [Key]
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Year")]
        public int ProgramYear { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public int ProgramStatusId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Program Title")]
        public string ProgramTitle { get; set; }

        public int ProgramTypeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Program Type")]
        public virtual SurveyProgramTypeModel ProgramType { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public virtual ProgramStatusModel ProgramStatusModel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SurveyResponseModel> SurveyResponseModels { get; set; }
    }
```

If the user does not see a `ProgramType` that fits what they want, they need to have an empty text box that allows them to create a new `ProgramType`.

```
Here is the ProgramType model:

   public class SurveyProgramTypeModel
    {

        [Key]
        public int ProgramTypeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Program Type")]
        public string ProgramType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SurveyProgramModel> SurveyProgramModels { get; set; }

    }
```

What is the best practice for updating 2 models in a single submission?  How do I keep my view Strongly Typed to `SurveyProgramModel`?  Create a View Model?

Answer (score 0):

You already know the answer, you would create a View Model and make the necessary changes in your HttpPost action.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking.  How does Entity know not to just create a new data table for that ViewModel though?  Do I have to specify that with a data annotation?

Comment: @user547794 You would return your ViewModel, which would contain all the information from your view.  You would then extract the details of your actual Model from the ViewModel and save those to the database. Your `ViewModel` = `YourModel` + `whateverNeededForViewModel`; just set your actual `Model` to equal `ViewModel.ModelElements` .

Comment: That's sort of where I'm confused.  It's a situation where if a "ProgramType" doesn't exist from a current drop down menu, there needs to be a way to add it.  So the model needs to exist twice essentially - once with a drop down menu, and once with a text field.  I'm really temped to just use the form collection but I know that's not considered good practice.

Comment: I have something pressing that is preventing me from spending time on this answer for you at the moment, I may be able to look at it later today.  I apologize for the lack of dedication.

Comment: No worries, I think I have something that is workable for the moment.